# Downloading high res pictures with Glide Library

Tags: android, image, bitmap, download, android-glide

I'm trying to create a "gallery" with pictures from a json file. I'm using a RecyclerView to show a grid with the pictures.

When a picture is clicked, it opens a new activity, and "sends" the picture info (url and name) to the other activity, so it can download the same picture.

Anyways, it doesn't download the picture in its biggest size or original size, and it looks kind of pixelated or low-res. I also want the picture to fill the screen without being scaled. This is the code and the picture filling the screen works, but still looks bad. I tried changing Glide default Bitmap format to ARGB_888, like in this tutorial http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en but didn't work.

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(wallUrl)
        .fitCenter()
        .placeholder(d)
        .into(mPhoto);
```

And layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="jahirfiquitiva.projects.activities.ViewerActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <jahirfiquitiva.projects.views.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_wallpaper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/walls_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wallpapers_fab"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/light_grey"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/semitransparent_black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TouchImageView is exactly this: https://gist.github.com/jahirfiquitiva/daaf5a81f09f21a44175

I also have a FAB which when pressed shows a dialog with 2 options: Apply or Save wallpaper.

Saving wallpaper works perfect. And applying does too, but while applying it shows a progress dialog using MaterialDialogs library, and somehow when the picture seems to be about to finish loading, the progress dialog freezes, so I would like to fix it, but don't know what could be wrong. This is the code:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                .title(R.string.apply)
                .content(R.string.confirm_apply)
                .positiveText(R.string.yes)
                .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        final MaterialDialog downloadDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                                .content(R.string.downloading_wallpaper)
                                .progress(true, 0)
                                .cancelable(false)
                                .show();

                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(url)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                                        if (resource != null) {
                                            downloadDialog.setContent(context.getString(R.string.setting_wall_title));
                                            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                                            try {
                                                wm.setBitmap(resource);
                                                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.set_as_wall_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Log.v("Wall", "It worked!");
                                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                                Toast.makeText(context, e2.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Log.v("Wall", "Error " + e2.getMessage());
                                            }
                                            downloadDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                    }
                }).show();
```

Hope someone can help me fix these 2 issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see the wallUrl value?

Comment: If you are  downloading images from network, you can use Volley[https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html ], which seems to be better at handling network image down loading and view updating.